# Start appium server programmatically in Windows machine

Tags: selenium-webdriver, appium

I am using Windows 8.1 and using appium 1.4.16 till now, I want to upgrade appium so I just uninstalled 1.4.16 from control pannel, then installed node.js after that installed  latest appium by using

```
npm install -g appium
```

when I run

```
appium -v
```

it shows me 1.6.4 till now no issues.
After that in my Maven project I want to start appium server programmatically but the appium is not saved in

`C:/Program Files or C:/ProgramFile(x86)`.

How can I start appium server programmatically?

I am using below code to run appium

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("\"C:/Program Files/Appium/node.exe\" \"C:/Program Files/Appium/node_modules/appium/bin/Appium.js\" --full-reset --local-timezone");
```

Answer (score 5):

There are 3 ways to achieve the scenario.
1)Using AppiumDriverLocalService

```
 public void startServer() {
//Set Capabilities
cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
cap.setCapability("noReset", "false");

//Build the Appium service
builder = new AppiumServiceBuilder();
builder.withIPAddress("127.0.0.1");
builder.usingPort(4723);
builder.withCapabilities(cap);
builder.withArgument(GeneralServerFlag.SESSION_OVERRIDE);
builder.withArgument(GeneralServerFlag.LOG_LEVEL,"error");

//Start the server with the builder
service = AppiumDriverLocalService.buildService(builder);
service.start();
}

public void stopServer() {
service.stop();
}
```

2)Using Appium.js with Node.exe

```
  public void startServer() {
CommandLine cmd = new CommandLine("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Appium\\node.exe");
cmd.addArgument("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Appium\\node_modules\\appium\\bin\\Appium.js");
cmd.addArgument("--address");
cmd.addArgument("127.0.0.1");
cmd.addArgument("--port");
cmd.addArgument("4723");

DefaultExecuteResultHandler handler = new DefaultExecuteResultHandler();
DefaultExecutor executor = new DefaultExecutor();
executor.setExitValue(1);
try {
    executor.execute(cmd, handler);
    Thread.sleep(10000);
} catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}

public void stopServer() {
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
try {
    runtime.exec("taskkill /F /IM node.exe");
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

3)Start Appium server using Command Prompt

```
public void startServer() {
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
try {
    runtime.exec("cmd.exe /c start cmd.exe /k \"appium -a 127.0.0.1 -p 4723 --session-override -dc \"{\"\"noReset\"\": \"\"false\"\"}\"\"");
    Thread.sleep(10000);
} catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
public void stopServer() {
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
try {
    runtime.exec("taskkill /F /IM node.exe");
    runtime.exec("taskkill /F /IM cmd.exe");
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

I found it helpful.Hope it helps. Source: http://www.automationtestinghub.com/3-ways-to-start-appium-server-from-java/

Answer (score 1):

You can try below code:

```
AppiumServiceBuilder builder = new AppiumServiceBuilder()
            .withAppiumJS(new File("C:\Users\<Username>\node_modules\appium\build\lib\main.js"))
            .withArgument(GeneralServerFlag.APP,  path of your app );
appiumDriverLocalService = builder.build();
appiumDriverLocalService.start();
```

Comment: is there any otherway to install the appium into C:/ProgramFiles

Comment: no..we are installing through npm right..so it will be installed in node_modules folder only

Answer (score 0):

If it's installed via npm then Appium can be run programatically. It shouldn't matter where Appium is installed. The below code mimics the manual behavior that we do to open it from command prompt.

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        try {
            runtime.exec("cmd.exe /c start cmd.exe /k \"appium -a 127.0.0.1 -p 4723 --session-override -dc \"{\"\"noReset\"\": \"\"false\"\"}\"\"");
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

There are couple of other ways as well, depending on how you installed Appium. You can check these here - [Start Appium Server Programatically](http://www.automationtestinghub.com/3-ways-to-start-appium-server-from-java/)

Answer (score 0):

```
String nodePath = "C:/Appium/node.exe";
 // Set path of your appium.js file.
 String appiumJSPath = "C:/Progra~1/Appium/node_modules/appium/bin/appium.js";
 String cmd = nodePath + " " + appiumJSPath;
 AndroidDriver driver;

 // This method Is responsible for starting appium server.
 public void appiumStart() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
  // Execute command string to start appium server.
  p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
  // Provide wait time of 10 mins to start appium server properly.
  // If face any error(Could not start a new session...) then Increase
  // this time to 15 or 20 mins.
  Thread.sleep(10000);
  if (p != null) {
   System.out.println("Appium server Is started now.");
  }
 }

 // This method Is responsible for stopping appium server.
 public void appiumStop() throws IOException {
  if (p != null) {
   p.destroy();
  }
  System.out.println("Appium server Is stopped now.");
 }
```